# Why eval() throws on undefined variables?

Tags: javascript, undefined, eval

The following code

```
console.log("1",eval(undefined));
console.log("2",eval(window.UndefVar));
console.log("3",eval(UndefVar));
```

produces the following output

```
1 undefined
2 undefined
UndefVar is not defined
```

Maybe IDK some inner workings, but throwing only on undefined variable and ignoring properties & undefined itself seems weird, even though it's the same in FF & Chrome, which leads me to assume it's somehow set in spec.

Comment: `eval` is unrelated here.

Comment: Code like that *without* `eval()` would also throw an exception.

Comment: This is a good valid question. The purpose of StackOverflow is to help people overcome ignorance like labeling this question with `eval`, not to antagonize them for not already knowing the answer. Therefore, it is very legitimate for this question to be tagged with `eval`: because on SO, ignorance is the lifeblood of helpful answers and learning.

Answer (score 3):

`undefined` is a name with the value of undefined. `window` is an object, you can dynamically assign names to objects, but trying to access one that isn't set, will return undefined. Also, the name `UndefVar` is not defined, so a `ReferenceError` will be thrown before eval gets called, as it has to evaluate the arguments first.

Comment: `window.UndefVar` is the same as `UndefVar`. Even though it's accessed in different ways it's unclear to me why it gives different results.

Comment: @ZeroUnderscoreOu a reference to an undefined object property is not a runtime error. A reference to an undefined *variable* is. That's just the way the language works.